# C# Constructing a Dynamic Query From DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Trying to Generate a Dynamic Linq Query, based on DataTable returned to me...  The column names in the DataTable will change, but I will know which ones I want to total, and which ones I will want to be grouped.

I can get this to work with loops and writing the output to a  variable, then recasting the parts back into a data table, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way of doing this.

```
//C#
DataTable dt = new DataTable;
Dt.columns(DynamicData1)
Dt.columns(DynamicData1)
Dt.columns(DynamicCount)
```

In this case the columns are LastName, FirstName, Age.  I want to total ages by LastName,FirstName columns (yes both in the group by).  So one of my parameters would specify group by = LastName, FirstName and another TotalBy = Age.  The next query may return different column names.

```
 Datarow dr =.. 
    dr[0] = {"Smith","John",10}
    dr[1] = {"Smith","John",11}
    dr[2] = {"Smith","Sarah",8}
```

Given these different potential columns names...I'm looking to generate a linq query that creates a generic group by and Total output.

Result:
LastName, FirstName, AgeTotal
Smith, John  = 21
Smith, Sarah = 8

Comment: `I'm hoping there is a more elegant way of doing this`  It is rather difficult to say since we cant see the code

Comment: Simply turn your `DataTable` into a linq object. It's very simple. Then `GroupBy` and `Sum` can be built live and ran however you want

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple converter for `Linq` you can achieve that easily.

Here a quick data generation i did for the sample :

```
// create dummy table
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

// action to create easily the records
var addData = new Action<string, string, int>((ln, fn, age) =>
    {
        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["LastName"] = ln;
        dr["FirstName"] = fn;
        dr["Age"] = age;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    });

// add 3 datarows records
addData("Smith", "John", 10);
addData("Smith", "John", 11);
addData("Smith", "Sarah", 8);
```

This is how to use my simple transformation class :

```
// create a linq version of the table
var lqTable = new LinqTable(dt);

// make the group by query
var groupByNames = lqTable.Rows.GroupBy(row => row["LastName"].ToString() + "-" + row["FirstName"].ToString()).ToList();

// for each group create a brand new linqRow
var linqRows = groupByNames.Select(grp =>
{
    //get all items. so we can use first item for last and first name and sum the age easily at the same time
    var items = grp.ToList();

    // return a new linq row
    return new LinqRow()
    {
        Fields = new List<LinqField>()
            {
                new LinqField("LastName",items[0]["LastName"].ToString()),
                new LinqField("FirstName",items[0]["FirstName"].ToString()),
                new LinqField("Age",items.Sum(item => Convert.ToInt32(item["Age"]))),
            }
    };
}).ToList();

// create new linq Table since it handle the datatable format ad transform it directly
var finalTable = new LinqTable() { Rows = linqRows }.AsDataTable();
```

And finally here are the custom class that are used

public class LinqTable
    {

```
    public LinqTable()
    {

    }

    public LinqTable(DataTable sourceTable)
    {
        LoadFromTable(sourceTable);
    }

    public List<LinqRow> Rows = new List<LinqRow>();

    public List<string> Columns
    {
        get
        {
            var columns = new List<string>();

            if (Rows != null && Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Rows[0].Fields.ForEach(field => columns.Add(field.Name));
            }

            return columns;
        }
    }

    public void LoadFromTable(DataTable sourceTable)
    {
        sourceTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(row => Rows.Add(new LinqRow(row)));
    }

    public DataTable AsDataTable()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable("data");

        if (Rows != null && Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Rows[0].Fields.ForEach(field =>
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.DataType);
            });

            Rows.ForEach(row =>
            {
                var dr = dt.NewRow();

                row.Fields.ForEach(field => dr[field.Name] = field.Value);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            });
        }

        return dt;
    }
}

public class LinqRow
{
    public List<LinqField> Fields = new List<LinqField>();

    public LinqRow()
    {

    }

    public LinqRow(DataRow sourceRow)
    {
        sourceRow.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(col => Fields.Add(new LinqField(col.ColumnName, sourceRow[col], col.DataType)));
    }

    public object this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Fields[index].Value;
        }
        set
        {
            Fields[index].Value = value;
        }
    }
    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return Fields.Find(f => f.Name == name).Value;
        }
        set
        {
            var fieldIndex = Fields.FindIndex(f => f.Name == name);

            if (fieldIndex >= 0)
            {
                Fields[fieldIndex].Value = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public DataTable AsSingleRowDataTable()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable("data");

        if (Fields != null && Fields.Count > 0)
        {
            Fields.ForEach(field =>
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.DataType);
            });

            var dr = dt.NewRow();

            Fields.ForEach(field => dr[field.Name] = field.Value);

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}

public class LinqField
{
    public Type DataType;
    public object Value;
    public string Name;

    public LinqField(string name, object value, Type dataType)
    {
        DataType = dataType;
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
    }

    public LinqField(string name, object value)
    {
        DataType = value.GetType();
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd just use a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> GroupTot(DataTable dt, string[] groupBy, string tot){

  var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  foreach(DataRow ro in dt.Rows){
    string key = "";
    foreach(string col in groupBy)
      key += (string)ro[col] + '\n';
    if(!d.ContainsKey(key))
      d[key] = 0;
    d[key]+= (int)ro[tot];
  }
  return d;
}
```

If you want the total on each row, we could get cute and create a column that is an array of one int instead of an int:

```
public void GroupTot(DataTable dt, string[] groupBy, string tot){

  var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  var dc = dt.Columns.Add("Total_" + tot, typeof(int[]));

  foreach(DataRow ro in dt.Rows){
    string key = "";
    foreach(string col in groupBy)
      key += (string)ro[col] + '\n'; //build a grouping key from first and last name
    if(!d.ContainsKey(key)) //have we seen this name pair before?
      d[key] = new int[1]; //no we haven't, ensure we have a tracker for our total, for this first+last name
    d[key][0] += (int)ro[tot]; //add the total
    ro[dc] = d[key]; //link the row to the total tracker
  }
}
```

At the end of the operation every row will have an array of int in the "Total_age" column that represents the total for that First+Last name. The reason I used int[] rather than int, is because int is a value type, whereas int[] is a reference. Because as the table is being iterated each row gets assigned a reference to an int[] some of them with the same First+Last name will end up with their int[] references pointing to the same object in memory, so incrementing a later one increments all the earlier ones too (all "John Smith" rows total column holds a refernece to the same int[]. If we'd made the column an int type, then every row would point to a different counter, because every time we say `ro[dc] = d[key]` it would copy the current value of d[key] int into ro[dc]'s int. Any reference type would do for this trick to work, but value types wouldn't. If you wanted your column to be value type you'd have to iterate the table again, or have two dictionaries, one that maps DataRow -> total and iterate the keys, assigning the totals back into the row